# What is Birkat Amazon?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My friend told me that after I eat I piece of bread I must say *Birkat Amazon*.

I like Amazon.com; I order many things from them. And, I guess I should say a blessing for Amazon, but, it seems more logical to do that after I receive my order in the mail. So, I have a few questions about this *Birkat Amazon*:

- Who and when was this composed?
- What does Amazon have to do with a piece of bread? I.e., why make this blessing after eating the bread?
- Do Amazon Prime members have a special obligation / mitzvah to say this vs. non-prime members? Do they get more cash back or perks if they say this blessing?

If you can find and / or link to the text of *Birkat Amazon*, that would be wonderful. I couldn't locate it on their web site or anywhere else.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Based on tractate Megilla 21b, I think you should say the bracha *before* the package arrives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with amazon.com, and in fact the prayer predates the Internet.

In the 1950s, Europeans made contact with a native Brazilian tribe called the [Kayapos](http://www.everyculture.com/wc/Brazil-to-Congo-Republic-of/Kayapos.html).  These people had many familiar traditions -- a rite of passage at the beginning of puberty, food-centered celebrations, and an afterlife built around communal assembly.  Consider:

> Special days for the Kayapos revolve around the seasons.  [...]  [A]n initiation rite is held when a boy reaches puberty or when he receives, as a small boy, his special ancestral name. [...] Naming ceremonies are regarded as an important means of helping the child develop social ties and an identity as a Kayapo.
>
> The Kayapos have a traditionally hospitable way of greeting visitors to their homes. Food is prepared by the women, and a bed made of bamboo is laid out for a guest.
>
> In that village in the afterlife, Kayapos believe they have their own traditional assembly building. Kayapo women, it is thought, are permitted only short visits to deliver food to their male relatives.

Right.  Who does that sound like?

The European explorers quickly realized that the Kayapos were one of the lost tribes of Israel and set out to teach them to live in the ways of torah.  They're still working on this (shellfish has turned out to be a challenge to overcome), but they've made progress.  The Kayapos now say blessings (still in their native tongue) before and after eating.

*Birkat Amazon* was composed for them.  It's not meant for the rest of us, and you should go on doing what you've already learned to do.

Comment: "The European explorers quickly realized that the Kayapos were one of the lost tribes of Israel " . Sorry, I'm not seeing how you deduced this.

Comment: @DanF from their rites of passage, traditions, etc that I cited.  Clearly they have the concepts of *bar mitzvah*, naming ceremonies as identity (the page is silent on whether their *b'rit* has a physical component), hospitality, seasonal festivals... sound familiar?

Answer (score 4):

> What does Amazon have to do with a piece of bread? I.e., why make this blessing after eating the bread?

When satiated we have a natural tendency to acknowledge [Seattle](https://www.amazon.com/p/feature/4kc8ovgnyf996yn) Di Shemaya.

> Do Amazon Prime members have a special obligation / mitzvah to say this vs. non-prime members?

No but remember that Kohanim have Priority.

And a freilechen purim.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually *lashon sagi nahor* (euphemism) along the same lines as referring to cursing God or using God's name in a curse. This happens at the point that the expected arrival date has passed and one's package has not arrived. Other appropriate instances include when no tracking number has been provided or when one has ordered a *sefer* on the "down low" and the package arrived unexpectedly and was discovered by one's spouse before the individual could intercept the delivery.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should say *birkat Amazon* after eating a piece of bread, but this *bracha* isn't limited to eating bread. In fact, this *bracha* should ideally be said whenever you do something simple which could easily be taken for granted. It's to remind us that Amazon provides for many of our needs (often in ways we don't realize [[such as by powering Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) which stores much of the data on the internet]) and deserves our thanks.

Since everybody gets so much benefit from Amazon, it's clear that it doesn't matter whether you're a Prime member or not. The benefits of Prime (especially when you subtract the cost of a Prime membership) are paltry compared to the total benefit we all get from Amazon every day.

The practice of saying *birkat Amazon* is unfortunately becoming less and less common nowadays. Many leading rabbis have theorized that today's [AWS S3 Outage](https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/) which has severely affected many sites on the internet is punishment for our laxity in this mitzvah. So it is very important that we all be very particular in our recitation of *birkat Amazon*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, seeing that Amazon.com has **EVERYTHING** and is just short of an omnipotent power, it is fitting to use it as an analogy for He who we thank for life and sustenance.

P.S.

Please say your Birkat Amazon with intense *kavana*.

Thank you,

A stock holder

Answer (score 2):

The source of Birkas Amazon is from the book of [Proverbs](http://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.31.29/he/Tanach_with_Nikkud?lang=he) which says

> לֶחֶם עַצְלוּת לֹא תֹאכֵל
>
> Didn't eat lazy bread - Which implies one did eat bread

Followed by

> קָמוּ בָנֶיהָ וַיְאַשְּׁרוּהָ
>
> Her Children praised her - past tense, that they made a fore-blessing

Who did they bless? The upcoming verse says

> "רַבּוֹת בָּנוֹת עָשׂוּ חָיִל"
>
> "Many females made an army" - the original Amazon tribe.

And the verse after says

> הִיא תִתְהַלָּל
>
> Should be praised

Which implies that there should be an after blessing.

But is Birchas Amazon the fore-blessing or after-blessing?

The answer is that since the last part of the verse says:

> וְ֝אַ֗תְּ עָלִ֥ית עַל־כֻּלָּֽנָה
>
> You are on top of everyone

And since everything (especially blessings) go after the end (See [Brachos](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%90) 12a), "being on top" implies the end blessing.

Comment: Very nice. I have to read the Brachot link to appreciate what you said. Happy Purim.

Comment: @DanF הכל הולך אחר החיתום

Comment: Thanks. I have to view this in its context. But, technically, the word החיתום means "the signature".

Comment: @DanF in context, it means the last part of the blessing (as in Baruch Atah Hashem HaMaariv Aravim)

Answer (score 1):

We say the Birkat Amazon after eating, because they were the ones who sent the books we read while relaxing and digesting our food, and we're thankful!  Popular lore has it that saying it prevents indigestion, gas, and familial discord(in that order)after meals.

Comment: Can you provide a link or support for your second sentence? Health science, in general, is conflicting, as you probably know. One day coffee is healthy; the next day it's bad. Similarly, I have heard that reading while eating causes distraction and makes people eat more. Family discord would probably INCREASE if everyone was reading at the dinner table.

Comment: @DanF - the reading occurs after the family has left the table, and is hopefully reading, learning, digesting, and discussing interesting reads, instead of watching the idiot box and falling asleep.  I wish I could find a Jewish Legend/Lore site that listed this one! It's origin is lost in the winds of time, most likely..But --that's why the blessing is done after the meal.

Answer (score 1):

As a way to thank the women who baked the bread, we make mention of the most courageous women in history, the [Amazons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazons).

Answer (score 1):

I know we're supposed to make Birkat Amazon after eating, but my cat is crazy enough already, and even cheese makes her barf, so I'm REALLY unwilling to give her beer.

Comment: I don't get it ...

Comment: @mevaqesh _birkat_ -> beer cat.

Comment: ah [15 characters]